# GUI designer claims undeclared variables

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I decompiled an executable that I lost the source code sometime ago. The code wasn't exactly the same that I've written it has some variables that I guess was added automatically compiler. So far, it was ok. But when I opened the GUI designer I get this error:

[image]

I don't understand why those erros since the variables are actually declared and the code compile just fine. I just can't use the GUI designer. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the designer to design a user interface, the corresponding code is put in a separate file with a warning that you should not manually edit that file, otherwise the designer will stop working.

The decompiler doesn't take into account the designer at all, so you'll end up with code that compiles and even functions exactly like it should - but the designer wouldn't be able to read it properly.

Perhaps the easiest solution is to create and design a new form, and copy in the code from the decompiled files afterwards (unless someone else has a great idea I do not know of, of course).